# ERROR in docker build : RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean:1.25.3 docker-workflow:1.28"

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am running the command
`docker build -t myjenkins-blueocean:2.332.3-1 .`
To build the docker image but resulting in error:

```
=> ERROR [6/6] RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean:1.25.3 docker-workflow:1.28"                          10.2s
------
 > [6/6] RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean:1.25.3 docker-workflow:1.28":
9.979 Multiple plugin prerequisites not met:
```

And finally returning error as:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins \"blueocean:1.25.3 docker-workflow:1.28\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

What would be the solution ?

I am trying different things but not yet working.

Comment: Show us your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

to install plugins use have to use jenkins core version "2.346.3"+

you can check like:

```
$ docker run -it --rm  jenkins/jenkins:2.346.3-alpine-jdk17 bash
bash-5.1$ jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean:1.25.3 docker-workflow:1.28"
Done
```

almost all plugins have dependencies, if you have pre installed plugins or unsatisfied dependency or dependency requires next version of jenkins core(like in your case) this script will fail

you can use
[this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool) tool

ps this script used in base jenkins image (output of this script you see when builing docker)